# How do I target a key that is inside an object with an index and that child object is inside another object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

In my reducer I want to target a certain key but I think because it has an index, I can't target it with the methods in my reducer. I'm new so help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
    export const initialState = {
    sheets: {
        0: {
            newTabsState: 'details',
            name: "Sheet",
            details: {
                projectUnit: '',
                projectName: '',
                projectId: '',
                projectCompany: '',
                projectDesigner: '',
                projectClient: ''
            },
            factors: {
                memberName: '',
                memberSpecies: '',
                memberWeight: '',
                memberLength: ''
            },
            forces: {
                forcesUnit: '',
                forcesName: '',
                forcesId: '',
                forcesCompany: '',
                forcesDesigner: '',
                forcesClient: ''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to target newTabState so I can add a value to it but my IDE gives me an error when I try to add an index at the reducer method

The code below doesn't work... can you tell me what to do? I want to learn how.

```
const setNewtabState = (state, payload) => {
return {
    ...state,
    sheets: {
        ...state,
        newTabsState: payload
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access `newTabState` like this `initialState.sheets[0].newTabState`.

I want to point out that when using an object in JavaScript as you do, there is no such thing as an index. An object only has keys and values and the key can be any arbitrary string or number. So what we access is a key represented by the number 0.

If you need proper indexes, you should use an array (which has the `reduce` method natively).

references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
return {
   sheets: {
    0: {     
      ...state.sheets[0],
      newTabsState: payload
  }
 }
```